# Check Box list collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have seen lots of examples in this Question, but till not concluded. and i tried with all these [EXAMPLES](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?source=search_app&gfe_rd=cr&ei=eZSjVa3xM4aDvASN8YrQBg&gws_rd=ssl#q=checkboxlist%20collection%20was%20modified%20enumeration%20operation%20may%20not%20execute.%20foreach). I am trying to remove empty check box list which are binding from data base.

```css
DataSet ds4 = getCheckBox(ViewState["id"].ToString());
        chkEnvironment.DataSource = ds4;
        chkEnvironment.DataTextField = "Environment";
        chkEnvironment.DataValueField = "Environmentid";
        chkEnvironment.DataBind();
```

But it is showing empty check boxes in my page. how to do it

```css
protected void chkEnvironment_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in chkEnvironment.Items)
        {
            if (item.Value == "NULL")
            {
                chkEnvironment.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection during enumeration. You could store the items you want to remove later:

```
var itemsToRemove = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (ListItem item in chkEnvironment.Items)
{
    if (item.Value == "NULL")
    {
        itemsToRemove.Add(item);
    }
}
foreach(var item in  itemsToRemove)                 
    chkEnvironment.Items.Remove(item);
```

the same with LINQ:

```
var itemsToRemove = chkEnvironment.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(i => i.Value ==  "NULL")
    .ToList();
foreach(var item in  itemsToRemove)                 
    chkEnvironment.Items.Remove(item);
```

Comment: @Vikram: have you used the debugger, was the list empty after the `foreach`(or `LINQ` query)? Is the value really `"NULL"` or `"null"` or maybe the `Text` property?

Comment: @Vikram: you could also remove them from the `DataSet` before you `DataBind` it.